How can I auto-approve quotes?
I am wanting to auto-approve quotes as customers approve them. Our company does not negotiate price, but we want the resource there for the customer. Is something like this possible?

What is your current scenario for approve quotes?

We manually go in and approve each quote. There's nothing to negotiate in terms of price, so it's a very tedious task of accessing magento and approving each quote. And on the weekends, we don't see it until Monday.

Have you use magento default functionality or any third party extension for the same?

I have not @DhirenVasoya. Are there any extensions you'd recommend?

Which step you are following into this entire system currently?


Create a after plugin 
class - NegotiableQuoteManagement 
method - "create" 
File - vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/Model/NegotiableQuoteManagement.php

In plugin, copy the code from
Class - Send
Method - execute
File - vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/Controller/Adminhtml/Quote/Send.php
Here use methods "saveAsDraft" & "adminSend" to auto approve the quotes.


Referrence:
Create Quote controller - vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/Controller/Quote/Create.php
Send Quote controller - vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/Controller/Adminhtml/Quote/Send.php
Model file - vendor/magento/module-negotiable-quote/Model/NegotiableQuoteManagement.php
